# How do we open another in the same form window in C#?

Tags: c#

What we observe in C# is that when we open another form it opens in a new window. How can we open it in the same window as in previous form was open?

Comment: winforms, ASP.Net, WPF?

Answer (score 0):

If your using WPF than just use a frame and then load the page within the frame. The pages to load must be of type Page and not Window. The frame makes it very easy to swap out pages. There is also a type called PageFunction that can be used to create a Wizard like structure. If need to pass data between pages then use PageFunction. 
If you are using WinFroms than MDI like @TylerDay stated is the way to go.

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like you want an MDI application.  If so here is a tutorial on that (assuming you are using winforms):

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/795470/Creating-MDI-Forms-in-WinForms